# PHP MySQL Set inserted value as PHP variable after using INSERT SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I am trying to figure out how to pass the inserted value which in this case would be a **status** value as a PHP variable.

This is my query for inserting a new row into the book table (PHP/MySQL).

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO books (booktitle,status,author) VALUES 
('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['booktitle'])."',
(SELECT status FROM user WHERE Id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['userid'])."'),
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['author']."')";
```

I have been trying to alter the query by adding ALIAS after the SELECT statement, but it definitely not working at all.

```
SELECT status FROM user WHERE Id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['userid'])."' AS $status
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Nevermind, I just realised that I should just add status=1 into WHERE clause.

```
 SELECT status FROM user WHERE Id = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['userid'])."' AND status=1
```

Comment: did you tried to paste that query into your database interface like phpmyadmin and get another error?

Comment: what error are you recieving? paste it here for more details and help you on

Comment: I don't receive any error, I just want to get back the status value as PHP variable. See my update. Thank you :)